# Object Required RTE 424

Tags: excel, vba

Afternoon,

Please excuse what is probably a really simple bit of coding, I am new to VBA.

Essentially what I am trying to do is update a spreadsheet from a Userform in VBA. I'm starting simple with effectively adding the selection from a ComboBox into my spreadsheet.

I want the code to look for the name in the spreadsheet, go to column 5 and insert the result from the ComboBox - in this instance the word "complete"

The code I have tried is below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 
Dim DOCUMENT As String
 
Dim Status_Cell As Range
 
DOCUMENT = "Report 1"
 
Status_Cell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DOCUMENT, Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B1:S107"), 5, False).Select
 
If ComboBox1.Value = "Complete" Then
 
Status_Cell.Value = "Complete"
 
End If
 
End Sub
```

When I try this I am getting the Run-Time error 424: Object Required error.

Any ideas? It's got to be something simple surely.

Thanks

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` returns a value, not a Range object. You should use `Match` to find the position, then `cells(matchrow, column)` to get the Range object.

Comment: Rory thanks for your response. 
You couldn't show me how to fit that into my code by any chance could you? I've never used a match function and am struggling to work out how / where to add it in.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Since VLookup returns a value, not a cell reference, you need a different approach, such as using Match to find the row position, then use that to refer to the cell:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 
Dim DOCUMENT As String
DOCUMENT = "Report 1"
      
Dim Search_Range as Range
Set Search_Range = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B1:S107")

Dim matchRow
matchRow = Application.Match(DOCUMENT, Search_Range.Columns(1), 0)
If not iserror(matchRow) then
   Dim Status_Cell As Range
   Set Status_Cell = Search_Range.Cells(matchRow, 5)
 
   If ComboBox1.Value = "Complete" Then
 
       Status_Cell.Value = "Complete"
 
   End If
End If
 
End Sub
```